# how to add other response codes in swagger ui?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have created one API spec document by importing open API dependency in my pom.xml but in generated swagger UI interface i have schema available only for 200 responses do I need to add other responses manually or swagger can generate it automatically

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @ApiResponses annotation to your mapping, for example:

```
@GetMapping("/example")
@ApiOperation(value = "Example mapping")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfull request"), @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal error")})
public void example() {
 // example
}
```

Comment: And this particular needs to be added for each endpoint .

Comment: Yes, you can also define other status codes, by adding another @ApiResponse to the list.

Comment: now i have added the response codes i have to add schemas for them all for others its okay but for 200 i have response entity<object> and its not being changed to response class.kinda https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification this problem i have all other codes but now 200 is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Swagger UI also has some default response codes that any APIs can throw like this:

[image]

But if you are not able to see any response codes, then you can use below code for configuring response codes for different APIs:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")})
public class Controller { 

    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Resource Not Found"), @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ok")}) 
    public ResponseEntity<> listApi(){
      // Code here
    }
}
```

Use can also use `@ApiResponses` annotation at class level, If you have some common response codes across multiple APIs.